# Swiper. Как перейти к конкретному слайду?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Swiper. Как перейти к конкретному слайду? Не нашел такого метода в документации. Нужно переходить к слайду по кнопке.

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-slideTo

Comment: Охринеть, спасибо)